# Пытаюсь сделать 'Пятнашки' столкнулся с проблемой

Tags: javascript

при нажатии на верхний ряд или нижний, выдает ошибку (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined), и кубик не передвигается

```js
let item = [
  ['1','2','3','4'],
  ['5','6','7','8'],
  ['9','10','11','12'],
  ['13','14','15','']
]
let itemEl = document.getElementsByClassName('item')

function start(){
  for(let x = 0; x<item.length; x++ ){
    for(let y = 0; y<item[x].length; y++ ){
      let number = ((y+1)+(x*4))-1;
      empty(x,y,number)
      itemEl[number].innerText = item[x][y];
      
      itemEl[number].addEventListener( "click" , () => {
          let itemMove = Number(itemEl[number].innerText);
          move(itemMove,x,y)
        });
      
    }
  }
}


function move(itemMove,x,y){

  if(item[x+1][y] == ''){
    item[x+1][y] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if(item[x-1][y] == ''){
    item[x-1][y] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if(item[x][y-1] == ''){
    item[x][y-1] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if(item[x][y+1] == ''){
    item[x][y+1] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }

}

function empty(x,y,number){
  if(itemEl[number].className === 'item hide'){
    itemEl[number].className = 'item'}
  else if(item[x][y] === ''){
    itemEl[number].className = 'item hide'}
}

start()
```

```css
.content{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.block{
  width: 248px;
  height: 248px;
  border:solid black 3px;
  border-radius:10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item{
  background:red;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border:solid green 3px;
  border-radius:10px
}
.hide{
  background:white;
  border:none;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: в проверке `if(item[x][y+1] == '')` добавьте проверки идекса. например так `if(y < 3 && item[x][y+1] == '')` ну и остальные.

Comment: вот так?
`if( y < 3 && item[x+1][y] == ''){
    item[x+1][y] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if( y < 3 && item[x-1][y] == ''){
    item[x-1][y] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if( y < 3 && item[x][y-1] == ''){
    item[x][y-1] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  `else if( y < 3 && item[x][y+1] == ''){
    item[x][y+1] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }`

Comment: ну нет конечно. если `x+1` то `x < 3` и подобное. ещё на `> 0` не забудьте. Вам надо просто не сделать выход за границы массива.

Comment: `if( x < 3 && item[x+1][y] == ''){
    item[x+1][y] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if( x < 3 && item[x-1][y] == ''){
    item[x-1][y] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if( y < 3 && item[x][y-1] == ''){
    item[x][y-1] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if( y < 3 && item[x][y+1] == ''){
    item[x][y+1] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
`
так?

Comment: Надо было сделать так:

`if( item[x+1] && item[x+1][y] == ''){
    item[x+1][y] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if( item[x-1]&& item[x-1][y] == ''){
    item[x-1][y] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if(item[x][y-1] == ''){
    item[x][y-1] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }
  else if(item[x][y+1] == ''){
    item[x][y+1] = itemMove;
    item[x][y] = '';
    start()
  }`

Comment: но не могу понять почему